# Firebase - Swift - Delete a child UID from a snapshot

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

I am trying to delete up the studentUser UID from my staffUsers. The UID I want to delete is nested in the staffUsers -> studentSession1List.
I have the UID listed with A Bool of True on creation.  This "studentSession1List" will have lots of studentUsers in the list.  I only want the studentUser that is logged in to have their UID(55FDLm9n6LccZBB7skaCbvfSHRz1) removed from the list.

```
let dataref = Database.database().reference()

    dataref.child("staffUsers").queryOrdered(byChild: "studentSession1List").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in


        for snap in snapshot.children {
            guard let studentUID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }

            let snapDataSnapshot = snap as! DataSnapshot

            var snapValues = snapDataSnapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]

            if var snapWithReg = snapValues?["studentSession1List"] as? [String: Bool] {


                print("This is the staff member")
                print(snapWithReg)
                print(snapWithReg.count)
                snapWithReg.removeValue(forKey: studentUID)
            }

        }


    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)

    }
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Full Function for Deleting and Adding the Student

```
    func didSelect(for cell: StudentSearchCell) {
    guard let indexpath = collectionView?.indexPath(for: cell) else { return }
    let staffUser = self.users[indexpath.item]
    let selectedUserId = staffUser.uid
    guard let studentUID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }

    let dataRef = Database.database().reference()

    dataRef.child("staffUsers").queryOrdered(byChild: "studentSession1List").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in


        for snap in snapshot.children {
            guard let studentUID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }

            let snapDataSnapshot = snap as! DataSnapshot

            var snapValues = snapDataSnapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]

            if (snapValues? ["studentSession1List"] as? [String: Bool]) != nil {
                dataRef.child("staffUsers").child(snapDataSnapshot.key).child("studentSession1List").child(studentUID).removeValue(completionBlock: { (error, ref) in
                    if error != nil {
                        print("Error: \(String(describing: error))")
                        return
                    }
                    print("Removed successfully")

                })

            }

        }


    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)

    }



    // Add student to staff list
    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("staffUsers").child(selectedUserId).child("studentSession1List")
    let values = [studentUID: true]
    ref.updateChildValues(values) { (err, ref) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Failed to follow user:", err)
            return

        }
    }

    // Add selected staff to student list
    let studentRef = Database.database().reference().child("studentUsers").child(studentUID).child("studentSession1List")
    studentRef.removeValue()
    let studentValues = [selectedUserId: true]
    studentRef.updateChildValues(studentValues) { (err, studentRef) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Failed to follow user:", err)
            return

        }
    }

    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

Comment: What is the result of the above code?

Comment: This is the staff member
["55FDLm9n6LccZBB7skaCbvfSHRz1": true]
1
This is the staff member
["55FDLm9n6LccZBB7skaCbvfSHRz1": true]
1

Comment: please add `print(studentUID)` also and see if it prints the right value?

Comment: I do get the student UID printed: 55FDLm9n6LccZBB7skaCbvfSHRz1

Comment: Database.database().reference().child("staffUsers").child("studentSession1List").child(self.studentUID).removeValue()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to reach the child that you want to remove using the following code and then remove it.

**Edit1:**

Since inside **staffUsers** we have keys inside which **studentSession1List** is present inside which the **value (studentUID)** is present that we want to remove, so inside your already written code I have added the new code, please check

```
let dataref = Database.database().reference()

    dataref.child("staffUsers").queryOrdered(byChild: "studentSession1List").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in


        for snap in snapshot.children {
            guard let studentUID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }

            let snapDataSnapshot = snap as! DataSnapshot

            var snapValues = snapDataSnapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]

            if var snapWithReg = snapValues?["studentSession1List"] as? [String: Bool] {

                //Added code here
                dataref.child("staffUsers").child(snapDataSnapshot.key).child("studentSession1List").child(studentUID).removeValue(completionBlock: { (error, ref) in
                    if error != nil {
                          print("Error: \(error)")
                          return
                    }
                    print("Removed successfully")

                })

            }

        }


    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)

    }
```

**Edit2:**

To delete the code once , we can use `observeSingleEvent`

```
observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

                        }, withCancel: nil)
```

Comment: I am getting "Value of type 'DatabaseQuery' has no member 'child'" for an error.

Comment: I am getting the same outputs. Nothing seems to want to be removed.

Comment: @AndyBernard I have updated the answer with method using callback , please use this method and see what is printed on the console , error or message?

Comment: Weird, I am getting the following message, but nothing is actually being deleted: This is the staff member
55FDLm9n6LccZBB7skaCbvfSHRz1
["55FDLm9n6LccZBB7skaCbvfSHRz1": true]
1
This is the staff member
55FDLm9n6LccZBB7skaCbvfSHRz1
["55FDLm9n6LccZBB7skaCbvfSHRz1": true]
1
Removed successfully
Removed successfully

Comment: @AndyBernard please comment other code and only use the code as mentioned above, I think you are using other code as well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154380/discussion-between-3stud1ant3-and-andy-bernard).

Comment: Getting the Removed Successfully but not removing anything. 'code' func delete() {
        
        let dataref = Database.database().reference()
        guard let studentUID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
        dataref.child("staffUsers").child("studentSession1List").child(studentUID).removeValue(completionBlock: { (error, ref) in
            if error != nil {
                print("Error: \(error)")
                return
            }
            print("Removed successfully")
            
        })
    }

Comment: @AndyBernard can you show the complete structure of your firebase database

Comment: I edited the original post to show the the complete structure of the database.

Comment: @AndyBernard I have made some changes in the answer, please give it a look

Comment: That is great.  Finally got the data to delete.  It just works too well and deletes the one I am adding to the staff.  What is the best way to make sure this block of code finished before mu next add student block writes to the database?

Comment: @AndyBernard sorry I couldnt understand your question in above comment, can you explain again please

Comment: On the users click I want to have two things happen.  The first is to delete the old student UID from the list(which you were able to solve for me) then add the student UID to the new staff member that was clicked on.   What is happening is it is adding then deleting both of the UIDs.  I would like to delete then write new.

Comment: @AndyBernard can you please show the code , where you are writing the code for add the new student UID?

Comment: I put my full function in the original question.

Comment: @AndyBernard I edited my answer , see if it helps you, check edit2